# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on JSTileMap

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, jstilemap

I'm trying to add a `tmx` file in my scene but I get

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

please help me

[image: ![My project structure is this]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its worked. I was saving the file in wrong way.it must save in Base64 compressed format.

Answer (score 0):

To make a number value an int use `Int()` instead of `(int)`.

e.g.

```
let a: Int = 5
let b: Double = Int(a)
```

Comment: Thank You for you quick response.But its an objective-C code,